# JavaScript dynamic variable in for loop

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic

I need to create some rules in javascript as below. I want to do create these rules in for loop however I couldn't able to dynamically create the variable parts.

```
var _docmap = document.mappingsTanimlari;
    if(_docmap.addServerOrClusterValue0.value != ""){
        arr.push(_docmap.addServerOrCluster0.value + _docmap.addServerOrClusterValue0.value)
    }
    if(_docmap.addServerOrClusterValue1.value != ""){
        arr.push(_docmap.addServerOrCluster1.value + _docmap.addServerOrClusterValue1.value)
    }
    if(_docmap.addServerOrClusterValue2.value != ""){
        arr.push(_docmap.addServerOrCluster2.value + _docmap.addServerOrClusterValue2.value)
    }
    if(_docmap.addServerOrClusterValue3.value != ""){
        arr.push(_docmap.addServerOrCluster3.value + _docmap.addServerOrClusterValue3.value)
    }
    if(_docmap.addServerOrClusterValue4.value != ""){
        arr.push(_docmap.addServerOrCluster4.value + _docmap.addServerOrClusterValue4.value)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I've to say that code looks *horrible*, but here's how to do it. You need to use bracket notation instead of dot notation so you can pass a string and concatenate the index:

```
for ( var i = 0; i <= 4; i++ ) {

  if ( document.mappingsTanimlari[ 'addServerOrClusterValue'+ i ].value ) {
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know it looks horrible because of that i needed to do it in for loop.

Comment: Yah, glad to help. I'd suggest you abstract the code into a function and cache the objects in variables so it reads more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like this?

```
var arr = new Array();
var data = document.mappingsTanimlari;

for(var i=data.length;i--;) {
 if(data[i].value != "") {
  arr.push(data[i].value + data[i].value);
 }
}
```